# How long can chicken stay out raw at room temperature before becoming unedible?

Tags: raw-meat

I know chicken isn't edible raw, but how long can it stay outside the refrigerator without gaining bacteria to where you can't even cook it?

Answer (score 0):

Chicken that has been defrosted in the fridge can be kept for an additional 1 to 2 days in the refrigerator before cooking; chicken that was thawed in the microwave or in cold water should be cooked immediately to be safe, but up to 24 hours or so should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Depends where you are located. In humid and warm places, the easier bacteria builds up. Generally you shouldn't keep raw meat out of refrigeration for more than an hour to be on the safe side.

If you are defrosting, put the meat in the refrigerator from the freezer the night before.